# Show only grouped products for specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function only_grouped_products( $tax_query ){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_type',
        'field'     => 'name',
        'terms'     => array('grouped'),
    );
    return $tax_query;
}
```

here's my code but I want to select grouped products for **Imperial Adapters** and **Metric Adapters** categories only

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128748/how-to-group-woocommerce-products-by-category-in-wordpress

Comment: i dont think that the right solution , but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter()` for this purpose:

```
$Imperial_Adapter =  array_filter($products, function ($record){
        //set your category name like in your db, i am using "Imperial Adapters" 
        //for understanding 
        return $record['taxonomy']['product_type'] == 'Imperial Adapters' 
    });
```

Comment: I assume `product_type` is the category.

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'only_grouped_products', 20, 1 );
function only_grouped_products( $tax_query ){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_type',
        'field'     => 'name',
        'terms'     => array('grouped'),
    );
    return $tax_query;
}

here's my current code